# How to pass data from a master array to multiple arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, function, merge

I have an array with subarrays, each subarray has 'type' (int) and a 'datetime'. I need to loop trought the array and create new arrays (or objects) with groups of these subarrays in a special way: every 'type' could be [0-3] 0 means startdate and 3 means enddate (1 and 2 are in between for other purposes). Every new array with these subarrays should start with 0 and end with 3.

Im not using any framework, only PHP5 and jQuery. The master array comes from a loop I made from a SQL query with GROUP_CONCAT. I just passed the concat fields to a master array but I need to regroup the subarrays to create some type of registries.

Here is the array I got with subarrays. They are already sorted by datetime, every type '0' means "start date / start new registry" and '3' means "end date / end registry".

```
$array = [
["tipo"=>0,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-26 09:35:30"],
["tipo"=>1,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-26 10:30:15"],
["tipo"=>2,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-26 10:43:12"],
["tipo"=>3,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-26 14:30:26"],
["tipo"=>0,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-26 15:35:22"],
["tipo"=>3,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-26 16:35:31"],
["tipo"=>0,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-27 08:31:57"],
["tipo"=>1,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-27 10:27:22"],
["tipo"=>2,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-27 10:38:31"],
["tipo"=>3,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-27 14:20:38"],
["tipo"=>0,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-28 09:39:42"],
["tipo"=>1,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-28 11:43:08"],
["tipo"=>2,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-28 11:53:19"],
["tipo"=>3,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-28 14:43:31"],
["tipo"=>0,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-29 10:30:22"],
["tipo"=>3,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-29 14:38:46"]
];
```

I need to create a new array with subarrays or objects by registry, a registry is an element who have startdate (type 0), somedates in between (type 1,2) and a enddate (type 3). Its important The next subarray have the startdate more current than the older subarray enddate. Every "tipo"+"fechahora" array have more fields (signature, address, etc) so I need to keep these as subarrays:

```
$newarray = [
    'registry0' => [ 
            "startdate"=> ["tipo"=>0,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-26 09:35:30"],
            "pauses"=> [
                ["tipo"=>1,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-26 10:30:15"],
                ["tipo"=>2,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-26 10:43:12"]
            ],
            "enddate" => ["tipo"=>3,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-26 14:30:26"]
        ],
    'registry1' => [ 
            "startdate"=> ["tipo"=>0,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-26 15:35:22"],
            "pauses"=> [],
            "enddate" => ["tipo"=>3,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-26 16:35:31"]
        ],
    'registry2' => [  
            "startdate"=> ["tipo"=>0,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-27 08:31:57"],
            "pauses"=> [
                ["tipo"=>1,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-27 10:27:22"],
                ["tipo"=>2,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-27 10:38:31"]
            ],
            "enddate" => ["tipo"=>3,"fechahora"=>"2019-05-27 14:20:38"]
    ]
];
```

I could use arrays or objects, I dont know hot to develop a loop to regroup arrays like this (starting at one field value and ending with another and so on). I dont even know if there is a simpler way. Any help would be appreciated.

If this could help: I need the registries this way to put into an HTML table, each registry in a row.

EDIT:

Iknow I have to use a loop but I dont know how to "get first element with type 0, create an array, include element, include all other element until type 3, close array, create new array and so on..."

In some code:

```
$newarray = [];
foreach($array as $element) {
if ($element["tipo"]==0) {
  //new subarray
  //include this in subarray
}
// include all "tipos" 1,2 in subarray
if ($element["tipo"]==3) {
  //include this in subarray
  //finish subarray
}
//incude subarray in $newarray
}
return $newarray;
```

I dont know how to continue.

Comment: Pretty simple with a loop, do you have an attempt?  But it would be easier and make more sense to just use `0`,`1` etc. instead of `registry0`, `registry1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this case a simple foreach followed by switch case will do,

```
$result = [];
$i      = 0;
$var = 3; // you can manage this at your will
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    switch ($value['tipo']) { // passing tipo value here
        case 0:
            // it will capture for same record for current value of $i
            $result['registry' . $i]['startdate'] = $value; 
            break;
        case $var:
            // detects last entry and will increment
            $result['registry' . $i++]['enddate'] = $value; 
            break;
        default:
            // if not 0 and $var then push it in pauses
            $result['registry' . $i]['pauses'][] = $value; 
            break;
    }
}
```

[**Demo Link**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/32ce0f16baa93d0817c5607a4eafd7e948bd3795).

Answer (score 2):

It is just a case of looping over each of the original array values and creating an entry in a temporary array (`$temp` in this case) with any values according to type.  Then when a type 3 is found, adding this to the `$newarray`...

```
$newarray = [];
$temp = [];
$count = 0;
foreach ( $array as $entry )    {
    if ( $entry['tipo'] == 0 )  {
        $temp = [ 'startdate' => $entry ];
    }
    else if ( $entry['tipo'] == 3 ) {
        $temp["enddate"] = $entry;
        $newarray["registry".$count++] = $temp;
    }
    else    {
        $temp["pauses"][] = $entry;
    }
}
```